# How do I display the current and remaining time of an mp3 in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want to display the current time and the remaining time of a file when an mp3 is playing. I'm also using a slider. I have tried this code but it didn't work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var durLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var curLabel: UILabel!

let duration = Int((player.duration - (player.currentTime)))
let minutes2 = duration/60
let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60
durLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes2,seconds2) as String

//This is to show and compute current time
let currentTime1 = Int((player.currentTime))
let minutes = currentTime1/60
let seconds = currentTime1 - minutes * 60
curLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
```

I have set label to show time.

Comment: I think you should use AVPlayer with a Timer to observe the time instead of AVAudioPlayer

Comment: `AVPlayer` not offer remainingTime attribut anyway your computation is correct.

to get active real time AVPLayerItem current time, check the `Timed State Observations ` section of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer